# Terraform The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply - works for 1 but not other

Tags: terraform

I have the follwing HCL code in a a terraform project:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "eventingester" {
  count = length(azurerm_windows_function_app.eventingester.outbound_ip_address_list)

  project_id = var.atlas_project_id
  comment    = "eventingester function app (outbound ip)"
  ip_address = azurerm_windows_function_app.eventingester.outbound_ip_address_list[count.index]
}

resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "inventoryapi" {
  count = length(azurerm_windows_function_app.inventoryapi.outbound_ip_address_list)

  project_id = var.atlas_project_id
  comment    = "inventoryapi function app (outbound ip)"
  ip_address = azurerm_windows_function_app.inventoryapi.outbound_ip_address_list[count.index]  
}
```

In seperate .tf files, i have successfully created Azure Function Resources namely:

- eventingester
- inventoryapi

In the above, code i am trying to create a MongoDb Atlas Network access IP Address whitelist. However when I run `terraform plan` I get the following error message:

[image]

If i look in Azure, both functions have outbound ip ranges in the network tab, and the `mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list` namely `eventingester` resource successfully creates.

Why can I not create the second `mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list` resource called `inventoryapi`, when the first block executes perfectly fine, if I have to do as it says and use -target, can somebody provide an example of this, as I'm yet to find one?

Comment: Did you happen to add the `eventingester` access-list after the `eventingester` Windows function app was already deployed?

Comment: I did yes.......

Comment: And I'm guessing you added the `inventoryapi` access-list and the `inventoryapi` Windows function app together, rather than deploying the Windows function first then the access-list later.  That'll be the reason for the difference in behaviour, but doesn't particularly help you with how best to deploy your configuration

Comment: Is the length of the address list determined by something else in your configuration? If so, you could try to use that as the value for the `count` field

Comment: What I dont understand is, why does it need code deploying to create an ip access list, once the inventory api function resource is created (in the terraform plan) i can see all the outbound networking, and its the count of that which is required, nothing to do with deploying a hello world function into the resource?

Comment: Interesting. Can you show the output of the plan that includes all the outbound networking? I haven't used Azure before so I'm not familiar with the details.